# How many colories does a *dog* burn when running?

Tags: running

I regularly go running with my dog around the park. He's a chocolate lab, 42 kg (all muscle) and we regularly do ~4 km in about 25-30 mins (he always stops to sniff). (For reference, I'm 81 kg.)

I run with a GPS watch that gives me my calories burnt, but wondered if it's possible to calculate how much my dog burned in the equivalent period? I don't know if it would be a simple reduction i.e. he's body weight as a percentage of mine, or if it's different because of four-legs etc.

I know this isn't the exactly a standard fitness question, but if anyone knows I'd be really grateful. Searches so far have only turned up calculators for the dog walker and not the dog.

Cheers.

Comment: The [faq] states that our site is for "fitness professionals, athletes, trainers and enthusiasts." You might want to commit to the [Animal Health and Behavior](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11526/animal-health-and-behavior) and [Pet Care & Training](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pet-care-training) proposals (currently in definition and commitment phases respectively) as you'll probably get better answers there than here. What you're asking for is beyond the site audience's expertise and knowledge base.